# confusion in run time measure with time.clock()!

Tags: python

[the description of time.clock()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.clock) :

> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
>   first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the
>   Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically
>   better than one microsecond.

I found others wrote like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import time

def procedure():
    time.sleep(2.5)

t0 = time.clock()
procedure()
t1 = time.clock()
print "time.clock(): ", t1-t0
```

but I thought when calling the time.clock() second time, the return value should be the run time since the first time call, so it should be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import time

def procedure():
    time.sleep(2.5)

t0 = time.clock()
procedure()
t1 = time.clock()
print "time.clock(): ", t1
```

can anyone tell me the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Those will produce the same result, so it doesn't matter in that example.  The first call will return zero (or some tiny number very close to zero), so `t1 - t0` will be effectively the same as `t1`.

But the first way is better because it will also work if you have previously called `time.clock()` somewhere else.  Using `t1` alone is not accurate unless you know for sure that `time.clock()` wasn't called elsewhere in your code before `t0`.

Comment: "The first call will return zero (or some tiny number very close to zero)"  But if the program runs for  a long time(`t0` is the CPU time of the program), `t0` may be a large number ,I think  `t1 - t0` will be different with `t1`. ps: I I know [on Unix  clock() returns the CPU time of the program](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock),but When on Windows, what will be return value when the  first call of clock() ?

Comment: @JeremyBai: You pasted the documentation yourself in your question.  It says it will return "seconds elapsed since the first call to this function", so on the first call it will return (effectively) zero.

Answer (score 0):

They both will return the same result because `t0` is going to be zero in Windows.

Use the first approach to make it platform independent. Your code would also work in Unix like system.